# Counting raster values in each polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, spatial-analyst, combine

I have a Watershed with ~100 smaller watersheds as a shapefile. I want to count the number of different land use values (they are in a 30x30m raster) in each of the small watersheds.

I tried combining them but nothing turns out they way I need it. Which tool or routine can I use to get this?

[image]

Comment: The best tool for that is tabulate area. Make sure to set environments.variables cell size and snap raster equal to ones from landuse raster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the powerful tools in ArcGIS is the [Tabulate Area](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm) tool, which allows you to calculate the area of each land use within each polygon in the polygon shapefile (watershed in your case).

The output will be a table that computes the area of land use in each polygon. If you want to know the number of pixels of land use simply you can create a new column and divide the area by 900 (30 x 30) and you will get the number of pixels of land use within each polygon.

Spatial Analyst extension is required to use `Tabulate Area` tool.

Answer (score 5):

If the smaller watersheds are in the same shapefile as the larger watershed, select and save the smaller watersheds as a separate shapefile. Run the [**Zonal Statistics**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/h-how-zonal-statistics-works.htm)tool with **Variety** as the target statistic. Your output should be a raster with the number of unique landuse values in each zone (small watershed) assigned to cells within the zone. You could explore [**Zonal Statistics as Table**][2.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific tool for your problem. It is called zonal histogram. You will use small watersheds as input feature and land use raster as input value raster. Then it will create a table that shows different land use counts as pixels for each watershed.

Comment: Underrated answer. I've been searching for this functionality for sometime in QGIS.